# Blank structs for selecting records with left joined subquery

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a few simiple Ecto structs:

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.ForumCategory do
  use MyApp.Schema

  schema "forum_categories" do
    field :name, :string

    field :last_topic, :map, virtual: true
    field :last_post, :map, virtual: true
  end
end
```

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.ForumTopic do
  use MyApp.Schema

  schema "forum_topics" do
    field :name, :string

    timestamps()

    belongs_to :forum_category, MyApp.ForumCategory

    has_many :forum_posts, MyApp.ForumPost
  end
end
```

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.ForumPost do
  use MyApp.Schema

  schema "forum_posts" do
    field :text, :string

    timestamps()

    belongs_to :profile, MyApp.Profile
    belongs_to :forum_topic, MyApp.ForumTopic
  end
end
```

And what I am trying to do is to retrieve the list of all forum categories with their last topic and this topic's last post:

```elixir
...
  def list do
    topics_query =
      ForumTopic
      |> join(:inner, [ft], fp in assoc(ft, :forum_posts))
      |> distinct([ft], ft.forum_category_id)
      |> order_by([ft, fp], [desc: ft.forum_category_id, desc: fp.inserted_at])

    posts_query =
      ForumPost
      |> distinct([fp], fp.forum_topic_id)
      |> order_by([fp], [desc: fp.forum_topic_id, desc: fp.inserted_at])

    categories =
      ForumCategory
      |> join(:left, [fc], lft in subquery(topics_query), lft.forum_category_id == fc.id)
      |> join(:left, [fc, lft], lfp in subquery(posts_query), lfp.forum_topic_id == lft.id)
      |> join(:left, [fc, lft, lfp], lfpp in assoc(lfp, :profile))
      |> select([fc, lft, lfp, lfpp], {fc, lft, lfp, lfpp})
      |> Repo.all()
      |> Enum.map(&fold_category_data/1)

    {:ok, %{forum_categories: categories}}
  end

  defp fold_category_data({fc, nil, nil, nil}), do: fc
  defp fold_category_data({fc, lft, lfp, lfpp}) do
    fc
    |> Map.put(:last_topic, lft)
    |> Map.put(:last_post, %{lfp | profile: lfpp})
  end
...
```

But what I find strange is that if the forum category has no topics (and therefore posts either), query bindings `lft` and `lfp` are not selected as `nil` but instead they are selected as `ForumTopic` and `ForumPost` structs with all of their fields having `nil` and therefore my folding function fails.

But if I remove the subqueries and instead do something like that:

```elixir
...
|> join(:left, [fc], lft in ForumTopic, lft.id == last_topic_id(fc.id))
...
```

where `last_topic_id` is a fragment macro that triggers a subquery for finding the last topic ID, then everything works as expected and I get `nil`s instead of blank schemas.

Could somebody please explain why things work this way and what would be the best way to go around it?

PS I don't like the latter option because it involves writing big fragments and probably much more slower from the SQL performance point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am positive that might be directly reported as an issue to *Ecto*. I am not a daily *Ecto* user, so I cannot guess why this decision was taken if it was done on purpose, but it looks pretty much like a bug to me.

The workaround would be very simple:

```
- defp fold_category_data({fc, nil, nil, nil}), do: fc
+ defp fold_category_data(
+   {fc, %ForumTopic{id: nil}, %ForumPost{id: nil}, nil}
+ ), do: fc
```

Comment: Yeah, the mapping is definitely not a problem, just wondered why it worked how it worked. I will try to reach someone to find out if that's an issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I definitely suggest posting an issue to `Ecto`.